# Recalculating and flipping normals not working—but manually re-adding the faces does? (Simple mesh)

Tags: normals

See if you can help me figure out what’s going on with this basic chair geometry with normals issues.

[image]

I recalculate normals and—still have a normals problem.

[image]

I check the face orientation. Ok, a little mismatching.

[image]

I manually flip the normals but STILL the problem persists. (I tried both red and blue sides to be sure).

[image]

So I try an experiment: manually deleting the faces and re-adding them. I delete a face, select the adjacent edges and hit F to create a face.

[image]

Still a problem with normals.

[image]

I try this again but this time selecting *all four edges* before hitting F to creating a face. Fixed normals—and this works for all the faces. Can someone help me understand why this is?

[image]

1. Why are the Recalculate Normals and Flip Normals functions not working here?
2. Why must I select all four edges to create a working face? Selecting two edges is (technically) selecting all four vertices,is it not?
3. Obviously to go about deleting and re-adding every face is needlessly time-consuming to repeat across the entire mesh. How do I go about this correctly?

Thank you for your time,

John

Comment: Hello :). My bet is on some double vertices. Have you tried *Object > Clean Up > Merge by distance*?

Comment: Hey, great idea but I had that thought too—and I found no double verts (and I adjusted the threshold).

Comment: Well, since I'm obviously not good at guessing, would you mind [sharing the .blend file](https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/)? :)

Comment: Here it is, thank you: [<img src="https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/embedImage.png?bid=ExwdnSMw" />](https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/ExwdnSMw/)

Comment: Also, just so you’re aware, when I add a bevel modifier to the mesh (which is where my noticing this problem began) it behaves asymmetrically, so it really seems like a mesh problem but for whatever reason, I simply can’t locate one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The mesh has some inside faces, and Blender is confused by it :).

1. Select the inside faces through *Select > All by trait > Inside Faces*
2. Delete them with <kbd>X</kbd> > Faces
3. Done.

[image]

**Credits to @John for finding the best solution for his own problem :).**

Comment: Excellent. Interior faces were the problem and I never had thought of or used the Non-Manifold selection tool (for me it was under Select > Interior Faces, perhaps renamed in the latest build). Thank you kindly.

Comment: You're right! *Select > Interior faces* is way faster, thanks for pointing that out :). I just couldn't make it work at first...

Answer (score 1):

Three more things to check since you already tried remove doubles/Merge by distance

- is it because of smooth shading on flat object ?
- go in edit mode with vertex select mode and see if there are extra vertices on any edges (You wont see extra vertices in edge or face select mode)
- In Face edit mode check if there are overlapping faces which did not get merged using remove doubles (Just keep clicking a face in wireframe mode ....if there are two faces you'll see the shading changing on each click)

Comment: It is smooth shading on a flat surface, although I *do* have auto smooth enabled, which shouldn’t be an issue. However, to add a bit to the mystery—when beveling, it behaves asymmetrically. Strange because I tried your other two bits of advice to no avail. I attached the .blend to an above comment if you’d be interested in taking a look yourself. Thank you for your assistance :)

Answer (score 0):

I downloaded your blend file

With blender 2.82.

Go into edit mode

Enabling face orientation

[image]

Select all

<kbd>Shift</kbd> + N to recalculate normals

[image]

Select the face that's still not having the right face orientation

<kbd>Shift</kbd> + N to recalculate normals

Then select inside

[image]

Comment: This was something I show and explain as not working in my question. Looking at your screenshots, it appears as though it didn’t work for you either. Thank you for your time, regardless.